# Python OOP - reset attributes ( explain )

Tags: python

I got a question to make a class twotowers, with first number - small, second number - big. represent it in a way and such ( as you will see in my code ).
Then I was asked: ***a constructor which receives two numbers and reset the attributes of both of them ( no know the order of numbers )***.
Firstly, the code:

```
class TwoNumbers:
    def __init__(self, small, big):
        self.small = small
        self.big = big

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Small - {self.small}, Big - {self.big}"


numbers = TwoNumbers(3, 9)
print(numbers)
```

Secondly, I didnt really understand what they meant.
what does it mean to reset the attributes? they mean to use random? that I can not know if big is the small and small is the big?
lets say small - 3, big - 9
so if I reset, it means I can have big - 3, small - 9? I didnt really understand, I will be happy to get information on what does it mean.
Thanks.

**EDIT:
Forgot to mention, I dont need an answer for it, just an explanation, what does it mean to reset attributes? the question is really not understanble.**

Second Edit:
Regarding on what I have been told here to do, is it good?

```
class TwoNumbers:
    def __init__(self, small, big):
        self.small = small
        self.big = big

    def __repr__(self):
        if self.small > self.big:
            return f"Small - {self.big}, Big - {self.small}"
        return f"Small - {self.small}, Big - {self.big}"


numbers = TwoNumbers(3, 9)
print(numbers)
```

Is this what they meant to do?

Third Edit ( LOL ):
Didn't realize I wrote the if statement at the repr, my bad... fixed it now.

```
class TwoNumbers:
    def __init__(self, small, big):
        self.small = small
        self.big = big
        if self.small > self.big:
            self.big, self.small = self.small, self.big

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Small - {self.small}, Big - {self.big}"


numbers = TwoNumbers(9, 3)
print(numbers)
```

How is it now?

Comment: I think they mean so that `TwoNumbers(3, 9)` would give the same output when you print it as `TwoNumbers(9, 3)`.

Comment: Is this homework?  If so it's fine to ask about it, but could you please quote the question *exactly*.  You're right that, as worded above, it makes no sense.

Comment: Its not exactly home work, its a pre-course for python before university ( engineering ), so ill have basics, as python is one of the hardest to learn :/ .......................................   about jonrsharpe, ohh, so you mean that no matter what I write at the twotowers variable, the order thingy, I should get small 3 big 9? wether I write 3, 9 or 9,3?

Comment: and Igananaut, its actually the quoted,  the question is basically in hebrew, I translated it myself to english, its same word to word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **a constructor which receives two numbers and reset the attributes of both of them ( no know the order of numbers ).8**

**reset** probably means to initialize the attributes from the given numbers.
They also say that the order of the numbers is unknown, this means that:
`TwoNumbers(3, 9)` would give the same output when you print it as `TwoNumbers(9, 3)`

You are supposed to check in the `__init__` method which number is small and which one is big, and put them in the right attributes.

Comment: Ahh I see, thank you :) I will try it.

Comment: Is it good? or it was not what they meant? Oh I cant edit here, I will edit my original post

Comment: @BenShaines It's funny that the question in Hebrew, I know Hebrew better than English... Send me the question and I will explain it to you (in what language you want)
right now I don't think you did as they asked, you are supposed to check what number is bigger in the `__init__`, and put the values in the correct place. Not in the `__repr__` method

Comment: Oh I didnt realize I did it on the repr and not at the init. my bad lol.
And yea I realized you are an israeli hehe.
About the question:     """  2. בנאי המקבל שני מספרים, ומאתחל את שתי התכונות (לא ניתן לדעת את סדר המספרים). """

Comment: And I just edited it again, can you look at it before you help me with it? I think I did it correctly now,  didnt realize where I did it ( which def )

Comment: Yes, now you did it perfectly, and according to the question. I will very much appreciate it if you will also accept my answer and I am glad I helped :)

Comment: Yea of course, I think I did it already, I did an upvote.

Comment: Oh the V statement, first time I see it, did it, thanks :)